# Why this difference in the method signature?

Tags: java, api, generics

From this [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.SortedMap%29):

1)The following is the constructor of a TreeMap which takes another map and use the comparable interface (of the passed map) to sort it.

> ```
> TreeMap
>
> public TreeMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)
>
> Constructs a new tree map containing the same mappings as the given map, ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys. All
> ```
>
> keys inserted into the new map must implement the Comparable
>   interface. Furthermore, all such keys must be mutually comparable:
>   k1.compareTo(k2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any keys k1
>   and k2 in the map. This method runs in n*log(n) time.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     m - the map whose mappings are to be placed in this map
> Throws:
>     ClassCastException - if the keys in m are not Comparable, or are not mutually comparable
>     NullPointerException - if the specified map is null
> ```

2) The following is the constructor of a TreeMap which takes another map and use the comparator interface (of the passed map) to sort it.

> TreeMap
>
> ```
> public TreeMap(SortedMap<K,? extends V> m)
>
> Constructs a new tree map containing the same mappings and using the same ordering as the specified sorted map. This method runs in
> ```
>
> linear time.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     m - the sorted map whose mappings are to be placed in this map, and whose comparator is to be used to sort this map
> Throws:
>     NullPointerException - if the specified map is null
> ```

Why the first signature is `public TreeMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m)` and the second is `public TreeMap(SortedMap<K,? extends V> m)`?

UPDATE: If not clear enough from the question, I wonder why the generics part related to the KEYS parameters in the constructors differ from one another. `? extends K` and `K`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Map` constructor uses `? extends K` because it's always good to make it as loose as possible.

The `SortedMap` constructor uses `K` because it takes the other map's comparator, and if the bound is `? extends K`, that wouldn't typecheck.

Let me explain in more detail.

Let's say we have classes `Base`, `Middle extends Base`, and `Derived extends Middle implements Foo`.

Then we have two special comparators, `BaseComp implements Comparator<Base>` and `FooComp implements Comparator<Foo>`.

Now we create a `TreeMap<Derived, String>` and give it a `FooComp`:

```
SortedMap<Derived, String> sm1 = new TreeMap<Derived, String>(new FooComp());
```

Note the constructor with the signature `TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comp)` that we use. `FooComp` implements `Comparator<Foo>`, and since `Foo` is a superclass of `Derived` (our `K`), this typechecks.

Next, we look at this map:

```
SortedMap<Derived, String> sm2 = new TreeMap<Derived, String>(new BaseComp());
```

Again this is fine. `BaseComp` implements `Comparator<Base>` and `Base super Derived` typechecks.

Ok, let's further assume that the constructor taking a sorted map had the signature `TreeMap(SortedMap<? extends K, ? extends V> map)` like the plain map one. Then we could now say this:

```
SortedMap<Middle, String> sm3 = new TreeMap<Middle, String>(sm2);
```

The constructor will then take `sm2`'s comparator, which is a `BaseComp`, which is fine: `Base super Middle` still typechecks. However, we could also do this:

```
SortedMap<Middle, String> sm4 = new TreeMap<Middle, String>(sm1);
```

The constructor takes `sm1`'s comparator, which is a `FooComp`, and `Foo super Middle` is not correct. So if this were allowed, it wouldn't be safe.

However, it is not allowed. In particular, let's say you change the bound on the constructor. I'm going to assign numbers to the question marks - not valid syntax, but good for understanding. So first you have the `SortedMap` interface which gives access to the comparator:

```
public interface SortedMap<K1, V1> extends Map<K1, V1> {
    Comparator<?1 super K1> comparator();
}
```

And then you have the `TreeMap` class with its constructor:

```
public class TreeMap<K2, V2> ... {
    private Comparator<?2 super K2> comp;

    public TreeMap(SortedMap<?3 extends K2, ?4 extends V2> map) {
        this.comp = map.comparator();
        // magic stuff to transfer elements
    }
}
```

Ok, in our concrete case, we try to do `new TreeMap<Middle, String>((SortedMap<Derived, String>)x)`, so match these types up: `K1 = Derived`, `K2 = Middle`. I'm going to ignore the values, they don't matter.

The signature of the constructor is fine. `?3` is deduced to `K1` which is `Derived`, and `Derived extends Middle` typechecks.

The first line of the constructor is the interesting part. The type of `this.comp` is `Comparator<?2 super Middle>`. The type of `map.comparator()` according to `SortedMap`'s definition is `?1 super K1`, so in our instance it's `?1 super Derived`.

So we try to assign a `?1 super Derived` to a `?2 super Middle`. In order for this to work, every base type of `Derived` must also be a base type of `Middle`. But we already showed a counterexample: `Foo`, the interface implemented by `Derived` but not `Middle`, is one. If there was a `Middle2` between `Middle` and `Derived`, that would be another.

So the compiler cannot allow this assignment and must thus fail to compile the code.

This was fun!

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid constructors, but as a convention, **you should always use the highest interface that you can**. So, while the constructor that takes Map would work in all cases, you should use the SortedMap constructor when you're building the TreeMap out of a SortedMap.

But why in this case? Because by letting the constructor know that you're not passing a regular Map, but a map that is already sorted, it will probably take advantage of it and run optimally. In this particular case, it's easy to see why building a TreeMap (which is a sorted map) from an already sorted map will be faster than building it from a non-ordered map (like a Hasmap): **the constructor will have to order a Map first but it will skip this part on a SortedMap** because it's already ordered.

Comment: I was more concerned  about the generics. why in the first K is ? extends K and in the second is K

Comment: Your edit isn't correct. It has nothing to do with forcing it to implement Comparable.

Comment: Indeed it was, your answer explains that part nicely. Removed my edit and upvoted yours.